# Testing that variables are both not empty and also an appropriate length

Tags: php, html

Im creating a form for editing customer bank details, account number, sortcode etc
If the customer leaves a necessary field blank the form is displayed with an error that they need to complete the appropriate fields

```
 if ($bankname == '' || $accname == ''||$sortcode==''||$accnum==''||$balance==''||$odlimit=='')
    // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
         $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
      editForm($bankname, $accname, $sortcode, $accnum, $balance, $passHint, $pin, $odlimit, $error, $id);       }
```

My problem is that I also want to check that if the user does input a value, for example in the account number field, that it needs to be 8 digits long exactly.
So I was thinking

```
if($accnum!=''&&strlen($accnum)!=8){
  // Account numbers must be 8 digits in length
    $error = 'ERROR: Account number must be 8 digits long';
 editForm($bankname, $accname, $sortcode, $accnum, $balance, $passHint, $pin, $odlimit, $error, $id);
}
```

But my problem is if the user then leaves the account number blank no error is recorded at all and a null value is recorded in the database.

Is there a way that I can check for empty strings and then if they are not empty test to ensure they are a correct length?

Comment: You might want to look into [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Something like `if (1 !== preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}$/', $accnum)){//handle error}`

Answer (score 1):

This what you mean? Is so, you just need to fill in the parts I named.

```
if(they are empty) {
  error 
}
else {
  if(not the right length) {
    error
  }
  else {
     run the edit
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Ruddy, thats it working now. It seems so straightforward not looking at it! Is there a way I can rate you for solving this?

Comment: Putting this as the answer and upvoting it if you can. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($accnum!=''&&strlen($accnum)!=8 && $accnum== null){
// Account numbers must be 8 digits in length
$error = 'ERROR: Account number must be 8 digits long';
editForm($bankname, $accname, $sortcode, $accnum, $balance, $passHint, $pin, $odlimit,     $error, $id);
}
```

try this way, it will help

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, I tried that but when I run the code again and tried to edit the record and left the account number field blank it still recorded an empty field in the database. Even if I tried a 4 digit account number it still accepted that and didnt flag an error.

Comment: 'strlen($accnum)<8' , post the full structure of code, may be I can study it and help

Comment: Ruddy's post below has worked for me, thanks for your help though!